# Mapping a view and a table to the same model in EF?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

### My Scenario

- I have a table of items, each of which has a priority and some other information.
- I also have a database view, which selects * from that table, but replaces the priorities based on some other attributes of the item
- Both the view and the table contain exactly the same fields, with only the content of the priorities changing.

In my code -- names changed to protect the innocent :) -- I have:

```
[Table("schema.Items")] //The table
public class Item
    {
      //...all of the fields that exist in both the table and the view.
    }
```

### Question

- Given this scenario, is there a way for me to pull from the view instead of the table but map it to the same model naturally? If so, how do I do that?

**Clarifications:**

- The "view" I mention is a database view that reads from the table but interprets the priority differently.

  - So, in this situation, we'd like to just pull from the view.
- The database view and database table have the same fields.
- I'm trying to find a way to avoid having `ClassA` and `ClassB`, both with the same properties, just so I can pull one from the view and the other from the table.
- I am referring only to reading data. There is no expectation of an update here.

Comment: The view and the table using the same class ? and you want to update certain property only from a UI object?

Comment: @YuliamChandra sorry for not being clear. We have a queue of items, each of which has a priority. However, when we look at them overall, we we want to change the priority based on some other factors (e.g. has the item been skipped more than once? etc.). To do that calculation, we're putting the items in a database view, that way we can just order by priority of items returned from that view. All the field names are exactly the same in the original table and the database view.

Comment: @YuliamChandra I added several clarifications on the question. I'm not attempting to update anything. I have a table in SQL server, and a view in SQL server. They have exactly the same fields (but in the view, one of those fields is calculated differently). Therefore, they could both map to the same model class in C#. I'm trying to find out how to avoid having a `ClassA` and `ClassB` just so I can read one from the view and another from the table, since both would have identical properties.

Comment: this is database first approach right? and the generated model produced two models (view model and table model), and you want to load database view model to database table model?

Comment: I'm creating the view in the database first. We started off with the Table, which is being mapped to a `TableModel`. Now I'm creating a view with a different spin on the table entries, but the same property. I was trying to avoid creating a `ViewModel` class to translate because it seems like 100% duplicate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `SqlQuery` to load from a query that is generated from view.

```
var db = ...; // instance of context

var q = db.Set<ViewModel>().Where(...).ToString();
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<TableModel>(q);
```

**PS**

If the view name has a pattern like `view_TableName`, you can just use `TableModel` to generate the query then replace the table name with view name.

Here is an extension method that could achieve that.

```
public static string GetViewSql<T>(this DbContext db, IQueryable<T> q)
    where T : class
{
    const string prefix = "view_";
    var tableName = Regex.Match(
        db.Set<T>().ToString(), 
        @"FROM (\[.*\]\.\[.*\]) AS \[Extent1\]").Groups[1].Value;
    var viewName = Regex.Replace(
        tableName, 
        @"\[.*\]\.\[(.*)\]", 
        m => m.Groups[0].Value.Replace(
            m.Groups[1].Value, prefix + m.Groups[1].Value));
    var sql = q.ToString().Replace(tableName, viewName);
    return sql;
}
```

Usage:

```
var query = db.Set<TableModel>().Where(...);
var sql = db.GetViewSql(query);
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<TableModel>(sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. To make sure I understand this correctly: This generates a SQL for that query against the view, and then executes that SQL query, mapping the results into the table model? So I still have to have `ViewModel` and `TableModel` classes, but the mapping is done for me. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, SqlQuery will map the result to matching property name, in this case both of them identical, you still need to have `ViewModel` to know the view name in the database `dbo.ViewName`, unless you know the view name, you can use `TableModel` to generate the query and then use regex to replace the name, some kind of pattern, `dbo.TableX` -> `dbo.view_TableX` probably easier

Comment: A nice novel solution. Thanks!

Comment: This generates a similar query that a two-table join for me (i made a view filtered on one table based on values from the other). I unfortunatelly get an error, like this: Must declare the scalar variable "@p__linq__0". Looks like EF doesn't take care of the variables it makes in the WHERE clauses :/